# Как раздать Wifi с Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

Я хотел раздать wifi Android телефонам с компьютера который в нём установлена Ubuntu 16.04. 
Как это сделать?

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Если вы хотите создать точку доступа под операционной системой `Ubuntu`, можете попробовать как описано например [тут](http://linux-user.ru/distributivy-linux/programmy-dlya-linux/kak-sozdat-tochku-dostupa-v-ubuntu-16-04/)